# Is it suitable to use MPI_Comm_split when assigning different jobs to different group?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I'm writing a MPI program where all processes are divided into two groups. Each group does different jobs. For example, processes of group A do some computation and communicate with each other, while processes of group B do nothing. Should I use MPI_Comm_split there?

Comment: If you need to do collective operations in these groups: yes.

Comment: Would you consider running the application as MPMD? That is, create two different binaries. One executing A and the other B and then spawning them as indicated in https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running#mpmd-run in case of running OpenMPI.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to add a comment but I'm new to stack overflow so don't have sufficient reputation ...

As already mentioned, sub-communicators are essential if you want to call collectives. Even without that, they'd be recommended as they'll make development easier. For example, if you try and send a message outside of group A then this will fail with a sub-communicator, but could cause your code to hang/misbehave if everyone stays in COMM_WORLD.

However, I would be very careful of going down the MPMD route as it may not be portable between systems and makes launching the program more complicated. Having a single MPI executable is the standard and simplest model.